# lodash .each and .trim ignoring array elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm trying to put together some demo lodash functionality and I'm running into some weird behavior.

I have an array of cars, plus some other non-string elements thrown in. I want to take each element of the array and remove it from the cars array, check if it's a string, if yes, trim off any trailing white space, add an 's' and push it into the pluralCars array.

I'm doing this in an angular controller and printing out the arrays in a view.

```
vm.cars = ['Saab ', 'Volvo', 'BMW ', 'Ford', 'Chevrolet ', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'BMW', 45, true, false, null];
vm.pluralCars = [];

lodash.each(vm.cars, function(car) {
  if (lodash.isString(car)) {
    lodash.pull(vm.cars, car);
    lodash.trim(car);
    car = car + 's';
    vm.pluralCars.push(car);
  }
 });
```

The output of `{{cars}}` is:

```
["Volvo","Ford","Toyota","BMW",45,true,false,null]
```

And the output of `{{pluralCars}}' is:

```
["Saab s","BMW s","Chevrolet s","Hondas"]
```

Notice that Volvo, Ford, Toyota and BMW (w/o the trailing white space) were not pulled from the cars array, pluralized, and added to the pluralCars array.

And then the strings that were pulled did not have their white space trimmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, they cannot be altered.

[`_.trim`](https://lodash.com/docs#trim) does return a *new* string, but you're just throwing away that result. You'll need to use

```
car = lodash.trim(car);
```

And apart from that it looks like you should simplify your code to

```
vm.pluralCars = lodash.map(lodash.filter(vm.cars, lodash.isString), function(car) {
  return lodash.trim(car) + 's';
});
```

without any `_.pull`ing - you don't want to modify `vm.cars`, and you certainly don't want to remove items while iterating it, as that will lead to skipping some. If you are looking for the array of non-string values as well, you can use [`_.partition`](https://lodash.com/docs#partition) instead of the filter.

Comment: That did it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Doing just `lodash.pull(vm.cars, car); console.log(car, vm.cars);` in the `each` loop will make it clear why you were missing some values.